# Не получается стипизировать элемент

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Делаю приложение на React + TypeScrypt + Redux. Портал фильмов. Фильмы тянутся с rest api. Реализую поиск фильмов. Сам портал и поиск работает. Не понял как правильно стипизировать list. Ошибка в аттаче. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { loadSearchFilm } from "store/searchFilm/actions";
import { selectList } from "store/searchFilm/selectors";
import routeMain from "./routes";
import InputBlock from "components/InputBlock";
import ButtonInput from "components/ButtonInput";
import SearchList from "components/SearchList";
import "./styles.scss";

const SearchPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const searchFilm = useSelector(selectList);

  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChange = () => {
    dispatch(loadSearchFilm(value));
  };

  return (
    <section className="mainSearch">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="searchWrapper search">
          <div className="search__title">
            Поиск по категории (раздел в разработке)
          </div>
          <InputBlock onChange={onChange} />
          <ButtonInput handleChange={handleChange} />
          <div className="search__info">Результаты поиска:</div>
          {searchFilm ? (
            <SearchList list={searchFilm} />
          ) : (
            <p className="search__error">
              Введите поисковый запрос для отображения информации
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export { routeMain };
export default SearchPage;
```

Сам компонент SearchList:

```
import React from "react";

import { IFilms } from "types/IFilms";
import SearchItem from "./components/SearchItem";

import "./styles.scss";

interface ISearchListParams {
  list: IFilms[];
}

const SearchList: React.FC<ISearchListParams> = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div className="searchList">
      {list.map((films: IFilms) => (
        <SearchItem key={films.show.id} item={films.show} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchList;
```

И SearchItem:

```
import React from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { routeMain as routeFilmsDetail } from "pages/FilmDetailPage";

import { IFilmsDetail } from "types/IFilmsDetail";

import "./styles.scss";

interface ISearchItemParams {
  item: IFilmsDetail;
}

const SearchItem: React.FC<ISearchItemParams> = ({ item }) => (
  <NavLink className="searchCardItem" to={routeFilmsDetail(item.id)}>
    <div className="searchCard">
      <div className="searchCard__left">
        <img
          className="searchCard__image"
          src={`${item.image?.medium}`}
          alt={item.name}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="searchCard__right">
        <div className="searchCard__title">{item.name}</div>
        <div className="searchCard__genres">{item.genres.join(", ")}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </NavLink>
);

export default SearchItem;
```

Типы описаны так:

```
import { IFilmsDetail } from "types/IFilmsDetail";

export interface IFilms {
  score: number;
  show: IFilmsDetail;
}
```

и

```
export interface IFilmsDetail {
  id: string;
  image: IImage | null;
  name: string;
  premiered: string | null;
  genres: string[];
  network: INetwork | null;
  summary: string | null;
  rating: IAverage;
}

interface IImage {
  medium: string;
  original: string;
}

interface INetwork {
  country: ICountry;
}
interface ICountry {
  name: string;
}

interface IAverage {
  average: string;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]